# CakePHP user login functionality

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp

I have baked my project and have got forms to add, view, edit and delete data on the database.My database includes a employee table. It includes a field called access level which is a choice of either "staff" or "admin". Also employee usernames and passwords are also stored in the employee table. How do i create a user login function so that when admin logs in admin is able to do anything on database while staff are not allowed to manage employees table?

Answer (score 1):

This question isn't affected by how/who logs in, it's about *authorization*.

### Use isAuthorized

Simple authentication and authorization is [explained in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html).

If you set up your application using controller authorization then the auth component will use `Controller::isAuthorized` to determine if a request is valid or not.

Just define the function `isAuthorized` to suit your needs

e.g.:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        ...
        'Auth' => array(
            ...
            'authorize' => array('Controller')
        )
    );

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        if ($user['access_level'] === 'admin') {
            return true;
        }

        return false; // always always default deny
    }
}
```

The above means that by default a non-admin user can not access any actions. In your controllers though:

```
class OthersController extends AppController {

    public function add() {...}

    public function delete() {...}

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        if ($this->action === 'add')  {
            return true; // Anyone can add
        }

        return parent::isAuthorized($user);
    }
}
```

This would allow any authorized user to access the others add action.

So, you can use [the auth component allow function](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public) to make actions or controllers accessible to anonymous users; and use isAuthorized to restrict access to not-admin users.